# Javascript-assigned CSS animations not working?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I was playing around with building a mobile web interface earlier, trying to keep things simple. I added a button that slid a fixed-position menu onto screen by assigning a class to the menu containing an animation. It looked good and seemed to be working so I added the inverse. However, when clicking to slide the menu back offscreen, the animation would not play, simply disappearing. The animation also does not play when clicking to bring the menu back onscreen after the first time.

Here's my code. Any help understanding why this isn't working as I expected (ie. animation should reset and play fully each time the class is reassigned) will be very helpful.

```
<script>

function setup(e){
 document.getElementById("menuButton").addEventListener("click", menuShow, false);
}

function menuShow(){
 var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
 if(menu.classList.contains("hiding")||
 menu.classList.contains("hidden")){
  menu.classList.add("showing");
  menu.classList.remove("hiding");
  menu.classList.remove("hidden");
 }else{
  menu.classList.add('hiding');
  menu.classList.remove('showing');
 };
}

</script>

<style>
 
#menu{
position:fixed;
color:white;
background-color:#f99;
width:100px;

#menu.showing{
 animation: 0.15s ease-out 0s 1 forwards popoutRight;
}
        
#menu.hiding{
 animation: 0.15s ease-out 0s 1 backwards popoutRight;
}
        
@keyframes popoutRight {
 from {right: -100px;}
 to {right: 0px;}
}

</style>

<body>
 <div id="menuButton">
  <h2>Show Menu</h2>
 </div>
 <ul id="menu" class="hidden">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: How did you run the `setup` function? Also there is a missing `}` for `#menu` CSS

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood the meaning of the forwards setting in animations. And you probably mean reverse rather than backwards. Check the definitions on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `animation`, I recommend using separate keyframe sets and setting the value for `right` to what it should be before an animation is triggered. The added classes of `.hidden` and `.shown` handle this:

```js
function menuShow() {
    var mclist = document.getElementById("menu").classList;
    if (mclist.contains("showing")) {
        mclist.remove('showing');
        mclist.remove("hidden");
        mclist.add('shown');
        mclist.add('hiding');
    } else {
        mclist.remove('hiding');
        mclist.remove('shown');
        mclist.add("hidden");
        mclist.add("showing");
    }
}
```

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  background-color: #f99;
  width: 100px;
}
#menu.hidden {
  right: -100px;
}
#menu.shown {
  right: 0px;
}
#menu.showing {
  animation: 0.15s ease-out 0s 1 normal forwards popoutRight;
}
#menu.hiding {
  animation: 0.15s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards popinRight;
}
@keyframes popoutRight {
  0% {right: -100px;}
  100% {right: 0px;}
}
@keyframes popinRight {
  0% {right: 0px;}
  100% {right: -100px;}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="menuButton" onClick="menuShow();">
        <h2>Show Menu</h2>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu" class="hidden">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

However, with `transition` it is much easier and if it is triggered while in the middle of a transition, it will use the current value of `right` resulting in no jitters.

```js
function menuShow() {
    var mclist = document.getElementById("menu").classList;
    if (mclist.contains("shown")) {
        mclist.remove('shown');
        mclist.add("hidden");
    } else {
        mclist.remove('hidden');
        mclist.add("shown");
    }
}
```

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  background-color: #f99;
  width: 100px;
  right: -100px;
}
#menu.hidden {
  right: -100px;
  transition: right 0.15s ease-in;
}
#menu.shown {
  right: 0px;
  transition: right 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="menuButton" onClick="menuShow();">
        <h2>Show Menu</h2>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu" class="hidden">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```